# What kind of electronics (if any) would stop functioning if earth's magnetic poles suddenly switched places?

Tags: electromagnetism

If earth's magnetic poles suddenly switched places, would electronics continue working as normally?

Would there be any visible signs in the electronics that a pole shift has taken place?

How about if there was a hypothetical situation of the pole rapidly shifting back and forth during a 24 hour period and then stabilizing?

Would this sort of thing affect any electronics at all? If it would, how?

Comment: Do electronic devices change behaviour when you rotate them 180 degrees?

Comment: Anything with a built-in electronic compass (e.g. many handheld/car/aircraft GPS units) would be affected in the obvious way.

Comment: Good point @Roger Rowland, thank you for bringing that out. I had read in some article that something like that would break havoc on electronics but could not remember the reasoning. Now when you say that, the article I read was probably based on nonsense rather than any science.

Comment: Yes, it may be that devices that have logic operating on an *assumption* of fixed poles might behave differently. But that's due to a false assumption rather than any physical effect on the electronics itself.

Comment: Some F15s* may fly upside down. 
(* Something like this happened with ?F15s?on a ferry mission.As the group crossed the equator some of the comms /nav systems "went out". Flying literally upsidedown is part pf what has been attributedtp this incident. AFAIR they swapped to short range inter aircraft comms systems & linked via escort aircraft to 'far away'.  No aircraft lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides magnetic (not gyroscopic) compasses and other sensitive magnetic field detectors?  Not much.  However, I would be more worried about HOW the poles got swapped around.  My guess is that we would spend some period of time with very little magnetic field.  This would have far more serious consequences.

Comment: Actually, magnetic compasses would *not* change their behaviour (being pedantic) - a compass would still point North, regardless of whether North has moved.

Comment: Well, it could cause sensor fusion based devices to go crazy since the 'magnetic north' indication would not match with actually going north as measured by, say, GPS.  But yes, they would still tell you which way was magnetic north, they would just point towards the south pole and cause a lot of confusion.

Comment: I agree (see my second comment on the question), it's not the electronics or physics that changes behaviour but it may affect the assumptions made by the people who designed the devices. [The poles wander anyway](http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/geomag/GeomagneticPoles.shtml), don't they?

Comment: It is indeed interesting to speculate what might happen (especially to power grids) during a lack of magnetic shielding from charged extraterrestrial particles while a pole reversal was in progress.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Good point! I suspect it was the lack of magnetic shielding that the OP was remembering rather than the shifted poles.

Answer (score 2):

A CRT based color TV will have a messed up display. Vendors used to make TV's specifically for the northern and specifically for the southern hemisphere. Not entirely sure what the display would look like, but I believe the color convergence will be messed up: the R, G and B images not lining up with the same pixel on screen.

Comment: What happens if you rotate your northern hemisphere TV by 180 degrees? This is probably for marketing or legal or power or broadcast signal reasons than any relation to magnetic north.

Comment: @alex.forencich I used to work at Philips. We actually designed and made the deflection coils for CRTs, different for northern and southern hemispheres. I don't think they would have gone through that effort if it was marketing or legal.

Comment: @Jippie. Never realised this but indeed the earth's magnetic field has a (small) vertical component which is obviously the cause of this problem. http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d4/World_Magnetic_Declination_2010.pdf

Comment: Interesting. I suppose this is an issue primarily for CRTs with vertical pixels as the small hemisphere dependent field would bend the beam slightly to the left or right.

Answer (score 1):

The earth magnetic filed is lower than 60 micro-Tesla and is quite constant. Most electronics behaves perfectly well within a constant electric field, even if it is as high a one Tesla. So unless an instrument is made to measure micro-Tesla, it will simply not be influenced at all by this change.